# Networkx viz - How do I sort nodes before plotting them in circular layout?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create timetables or cardioid graph using network in python this is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
n = 10
for i in range(1,n):
    if i*2 < n:
        G.add_node(i, weight=i)
        G.add_node(i*2, weight=i*2)
        G.add_edge(i, i*2)
    else:
        G.add_node(i, weight=i)
        G.add_node(i*2-n, weight=i*2-n)
        G.add_edge(i,i*2 - n)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), node_size=1000)
```

But then I am getting something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EW95.png)
Whereas I want nodes to be in a a sorted manner like 0,1,2... in circular format, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(sorted(G.nodes()), node_size=1000)
```

to get the nodes sorted in an anticlockwise manner.
Otherwise, for a clockwise ordering you can use

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(sorted(G.nodes(), reverse=True)), node_size=1000)
```

Example:

[image]